# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity - Testing Amazon Mobile Ads

Tags: android

I've posted this question on the Amazon Developer Forum and haven't received an answer in 4 days, I've also sent it to Amazon developer support and haven't received an answer in the same time frame, so I'm here, hoping someone can help.

I'm trying to add 'mobile ads' to a new application. I'm working with Eclipse - Helios

In my manifest I have the correct permissions set
I have the Libraries set, I've checked the build path and project properties and things seem fine, The project builds with no issues

In my code 
I have inserted the Application Key
I have inserted AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);
I have inserted AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);

When I use 'Run As - Android App' the app crashes with this and select either of my normal testing devices (Kindle Fire or Samsung Galaxy Tab), it builds find and begins to load the apk unto the the device and then this:

> 

07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): *java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thecountrylife/com.thecountrylife.MenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.thecountrylife.MenuActivity" on path: /data/app/com.thecountrylife-2.apk:/system/app/MetricsApi-2037410.apk:/system/app/com.amazon.dp.logger.apk*
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2142)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5152)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.thecountrylife.MenuActivity" on path: /data/app/com.thecountrylife-2.apk:/system/app/MetricsApi-2037410.apk:/system/app/com.amazon.dp.logger.apk
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1055)
07-24 14:30:40.722: E/AndroidRuntime(2904): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2133)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please paste your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than continue to wait for Amazon or beat my head over the issue I simply switched over to Google MobAds, so my manifest is now what Google requires.  Thanks anyway.